# Low resolution icons in the application switcher

Tags: unity, application-switcher

I'm on Precise 12.04 with Unity as Shell.
With simple Application Switcher enabled in CCSM, all icons are showing in low resolution.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: can u please post a screen shot

Comment: For now I'm using to Unity switcher, but soon will reup the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug
Reported [Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager/+bug/993261) and [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/387828)

Comment: possibly - the first one is relevant - the other two links are for older  ubuntu versions - if you follow one of the links, it says it was fixed in natty.  Thus, its too early to say its a definite bug until one of the developers responds to the latest bug report.

Comment: the 2nd is actually a duplicate of the 3rd .. il remove it..