# Pixelated and low resolution icons in Unity dock

Tags: 16.04, unity, icons

I am on 16.04 LTS. I have done some digging and all I've found was 5 years old question that says "It's a reported bug".

[Low resolution icons in the application switcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130047/low-resolution-icons-in-the-application-switcher)

Is there any way to fix this?

[image]